# Bash Shell Script - If with Find not returning what I expected

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, find

My program:

```
find teste1 | while read -r firstResult
do
find teste2 | while read -r secondResult
do
if [[ $firstResult == $secondResult ]]; then
echo "$firstResult" "$secondResult" > equal.lst
else
echo "$firstResult" "$secondResult" > notEqual.lst
fi
done
done
```

Now, my problem is that when it searches the contents of the find on the "`IF`" command, it isn't saving the differences on "notEqual" nor the equals to "equal".

Am I doing something wrong or missing anything?

If you don't know the answer or can at least point me in a better direction, I would trully appreciate it! :)

What I want from the program as a total:

Search a directory and whilst doing this, search another directory, if any of the searches on those directories match each other, save it to "equal", if not, save it to "notequal".

I need this program so I can find which files have been renamed or deleted and so on.

----------EDIT----------------

After seeing other comments, I tried messing around with Differ:

```
find teste1 -type f | while read -r firstResult
do
find teste2 -type f | while read -r secondResult
do
diff -rs $firstResult $secondResult
done
done
```

The problem with this one is that it does find some "identical" files, however, the "identical" for this means the files with the same .extension, could I remove this possibility somehow?

----------EDIT 2----------------

Ok, so, hopefully this will be my last EDIT and will finally post an ANSWER, I did some modifications to my original program and I know it's not as farfetched as most of those that are around here but it got me pretty damn close to where I wanted and since I am a noob, please bare with extensiveness of the program when it could be much smaller:

```
find teste1 -type f | while read -r firstResult
do
find teste2 -type f | while read -r secondResult
do
firstName=${firstResult##*[/|\\]}
secondName=${secondResult##*[/|\\]}
if [[ $firstName == $secondName ]]; then
echo "$firstResult" "$secondResult" >> equal.lst
else
echo "$firstResult" "$secondResult" >> notEqual.lst
fi
done
done
```

Now... My final dillema and I think it's quite easy: This only finds and saves files with the exact cases and I'd like, imagine as this -> You have a folder on 1 directory, now someone comes and saves another folder just like that (different content) on another directory but "renames" the folder to a different casing, as in 1st dir "tEsT" and 2nd dir "test". The program won't consider those two as the same, how do I change this? I have heard of case sensitive but I don't know exactly "where" to put it.

Comment: have a look at the `diff` tool, this is what the tool excels at, check the options for recursive and quit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just just use `diff` and `comm` here:

**UPDATE:**

```
(cd teste1 && find . \! -name '.') > list1
(cd teste2 && find . \! -name '.') > list2

# matching names
grep -f list1 list2 > equal.lst

# non matching names
grep -v -f list1 list2 > notEqual.lst
grep -v -f list2 list1 >> notEqual.lst
```

Comment: Good solution, but a couple of caveats. list1 and list2 will be in different directories, so you will need a full path in your "comm". And also, it won't find files with the same name and size but different content.

Comment: Or do    (cd teste1 && find .) > list1

Comment: I'll keep trying with something similar as to what Anubhava did, with separating the "equal" of the "notEqual" and see what I can come up with

Comment: Ok check my updated answer now. It produces both `equal` and `notEqual` files in single pass.

Comment: Thanks a bunch @anubhava :) Unfortunately I don't have "awk" installed or at least it never works for me, keeps saying "awk" command not found.
However, since you might have seen from my last update, I am quite near to the purpose of the program.
Thanks a lot for the help and different solution :) I love brainstorming

Comment: awk not there is very strange, haven't seen any Unix system without awk. Do you have grep?

Comment: @anubhava: Well, I'm using Windows system, maybe that's why? :P
Ok, it's working now with Grep! THANKS! :D Now I must fine tune it to give out exactly what I need hehehe :) Could you perhaps look at my last edit and try to help out there as well? Please?

Comment: Actually that nested loop with 2 find is not going to give correct result, that was the whole reason I suggested a different approach.

Comment: Yes, indeed, it did not, I'll try out your different approach, it's much smaller than mine, which means it should be faster heheh. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help you. If your directories are called "teste1" and "teste2", you will need to run the following command which looks in both directories and calculates a checksum for all files in there and then the outputs are sorted, so you will see duplicates below each other.

```
find teste1 teste2 -type f -exec md5 -r {} \; | sort
```

Example:

```
4eccdeeb6650531664510f282cbf3e06 ./Screen Shot 2014-01-29 at 14.30.51.png
66500a7f2a0e5743b82088db7f9d6876 ./a
66500a7f2a0e5743b82088db7f9d6876 ./vt.csv
cdd8ec3e1ec4e0bfd4cd9b5d87fe2fc5 ./Screen Shot 2014-01-29 at 14.29.55.png
```

you can see files "a" and "vt.csv" (in the 2nd and 3rd lines) have identical checksums and therefore have the same content as each other, but different names.

Comment: This does sound interesting. How exactly does MD5 differ from a file name? MD5 seems like a rather "unique" identification of a file/folder.

Comment: md5 calculates a checksum which depends entirely on the contents of the file, not its name - it is a sort of unique identifier.

Comment: This solution will not tell you if any files are missing from teste2 vis-a-vis teste1, by the way.

Comment: So, md5 calculates checksum depending on the content of the file meaning what exactly? If a "test.xls" on a directory and "test.xls" on another directory will have different checksums DEPENDING on what it's on them? But doesn't that already "kill" the whole purpose of this find-difference, business? Sorry for my dumb questions :(

Comment: If the content of "test.xls" in directory1 is the same as the content of "fred.xls" in directory2 then the two checksums will be identical so you will see them below each other in your list as identical although they clearly have different names and locations.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
find teste1 -type f | while read -r a
do
    echo Checking file: $a
    srchfor=$(basename "$a")
    lines=$(find teste2 -type f -iname "$srchfor"|wc -l)
    if [ $lines -gt 0 ]; then
       echo Files with names like $a === $(find teste2 -type f -iname "$srchfor")
    fi
done
```

It will tell you, for example, that there is a file called "c.html" in teste1, and another file called "C.HTML" in teste2/sub/directory/somewhere.

Comment: Hmm, this did sound exactly what i needed. Unfortunately, at "if [ $lines -gt 0 ]; then" it says -> : integer expression expected

Comment: I added the interpreter to the first line and also quoted some variables, specifically "$srchfor". Just copy it all again :-)

Comment: Well, about the "first line", I already have as "#!/bin/bash" :) Should I change to yours?
As for the rest, I already changed it all and, like I said before, at the "if" it still says "integer expression expected" :(

Comment: I didn't realise you were using Windows! If you tag questions with "bash" and "shell" and "find" people will assume you are on a "proper" Unix/Linux computer because those tools are not in Windows.

Comment: Oooh, I am terribly sorry, omg :( Didn't quite realize that. Please do forgive me! Should I just tag with "Windows" along with "Shell" and "Find" then? Without "bash"?

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt could never work because `teste1/file` will never be equal to `teste2/file`.

Anyhow, try this instead:

```
find teste1 | while read -r firstResult
do
    secondResult=teste2/${firstResult#teste1/}
    if [ -e "$secondResult" ]; then
        echo "$firstResult" "$secondResult" >> equal.lst
    else
        echo "$firstResult" "$secondResult" >> notEqual.lst
    fi
done
```

To do this with `diff`, maybe something like

```
diff <(cd teste1; find .) <(cd teste2; find .)
```

However, this will only list out the differences, not the similarities.

Neither of these examine the contents of the files, just the file names.  If you actually want to find differences in files with the same names, try

```
diff -burNad teste1 teste2
```